# In Excel, set currency format to currencies with exotic symbols (glyphs)

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel (2010) I have a problem to programmatically assign currency formats to cells.

I often need to assign the currency format "Bulgarian Lev" (symbol: лв.) to columns in my Excel spreadsheets. Doing this manually (using what Excel's ribbon offers) is unacceptably tedious work, because MS has managed to hide my preferred currencies under tons of Arabic and Asian currencies, and I have not figured out a shortcut how to quickly scroll down to exactly "Bulgarian Lev".

Therefore I tried to record a macro for this procedure. With the procedure recorded once, it should then be possible to repeat the assignment on any range of cells in any worksheet by just running the Macro.

However, when using this Macro testwise on a bunch of cells, they happened to look like this:

500,00 ??.

whereas expected was:

500,00 лв.

Obviously, Excel in this case does not cope with the Cyrillic letters.

Any solution available for this?

Comment: Could you please share your code so that we can test it on our side?

Comment: Hello Christian, if I understand well you solved your own problem right? If so, please do not forget to accept your own answer when it will be possible. Just for your information, the fact that you see ?? instead of the cyrillic characters in the VBE is because the Editor does not support those characters, hence the replacement you did with the Chr() elements looks necessary and correct to me.

Comment: P.s. I guess you noticed that in your macro you're applying the formatting only to `Selection`, that means you have to run the macro after having previously selected the range you want to apply the change. If you want it to make it automatically, you can always replace your `Selection` with something like `Range("A1:A10")` (or whatever is your desired range).

Comment: Hello Matteo, thank you for your additional suggestions. Using "Selection" is on purpose here, due to the way I intend to use this macro. For "accepting the answer": sorry, this may sound stupid: I do not see no button or the like to do this... What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know, I can't see it cause I'm not the person who asked :) But you should see it right below the number of likes and the two upvote/downvote arrows, maybe try to hover the mouse on it and see if it appears (but I think you need to wait 48 hours before being able to accept it).

Comment: Ah! Now I see it. A grey v-shaped tick-mark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem.

The recorded macro consists of the following line of code:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0.00 [$??.-402]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$??.-402]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$??.-402]_-;_-@_-"
```

The string between the quotation marks defines the number format. You can look this up also by clicking Home --> Format --> Format Cells --> Custom, to get the current definition displayed.

In this line of code, everywhere where "лв." (for Bulgarian Lev) is expected, Excel's VBA machine put two question marks. That's obviously a bug in the system. But luckily it can be fixed by altering the line by replacing each ?? by " & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & " like this:

```
  Selection.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0.00 [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;_-* ""-""" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & " [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;_-@_-"
```

ChrW(1083) generates the Cyrillic л

ChrW(1074) generates the Cyrillic в

Mind the additional quotation marks that limit the string sections before and after each occurence of " & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & "!!

For identifying other character codes (Decimal notation) for other exotic currencies that are not displayed correctly, look them up in any character code table such as http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode-decimal.html.

PS: Here is the complete macro, with some annotation:

```
Sub SetCurrencyLeva()

' Purpose: Set the number format of a range of cells to "Currency:  Bulgarian Lev", with correctly displayed Cyrillic letters
' For using it, mark (select) the range of cells you want to format, then run the macro

' Explanation: in VBA, Cyrillic glyphs cannot be set directly; therefore we generate them using the ChrW() function

' This is what Excel's macro recorder initially produced
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0.00 [$??.-402]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$??.-402]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$??.-402]_-;_-@_-"
     'Left here for documentation. Value will be overwritten by the next line of code

' Adjusted string that makes Cyrillic letters appear correctly, with ChrW(1083) vor Cyrillic l, and ChrW(1074) for Cyrillic v

    Selection.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0.00 [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;_-* ""-"" [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;_-@_-"

' Note: on 21/01/2016 I slightly changed the string above in order to fix a bug (double currency symbol when value is 0). The previous, faulty string was: 

   'Selection.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0.00 [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;_-* ""-""" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & " [$" & ChrW(1083) & ChrW(1074) & ".-402]_-;_-@_-"
    '(Left here for documentation)






End Sub
```

Comment: On 21/01/2016 I altered the initial solution in order to fix a bug causing the currency symbol appear twice when the value is 0 (represented by hyphen). Documentation on this is now included in the macro code depicted above.